# Positioning div to top of viewport using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I position the #lightbox div to always be at the top of the viewport?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mehr').click(function() {
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    $('#lightbox').css({'visibility' : 'visible'}).animate({'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)', 'opacity': '1'}, 500);
});
```

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: How does your HTML/CSS look like? Make it overlaying the viewport you can use `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` in combination with a high `z-index`. A jsfiddle would be a great help..

Comment: use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570075/what-is-the-logic-of-lightbox-2-on-where-to-position-the-popup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this with simple HTML / CSS : http://jsfiddle.net/wZDXg/

HTML:

```
<div id="lightbox">Light box</div>
<div id="other">Other content</div>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    margin:0;    
}

#lightbox
{
    background-color:gray;
    width : 100%;
    height: 150px;
    position : fixed;
    top      : 0;
    margin-bottom:150px;
}

#other
{
    margin-top : 150px; 
    height     : 1500px;
    background-color:#999999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS :

```
#lightbox {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `position:absolute` and `z-index:1000`

Answer (score 0):

```
position: fixed; top:0; z-index:999999;
```